# User defined printf output conversions for Windows?

Tags: windows, printf

I'd like to define my own printf output conversions:

```
printf("%T", widget);
```

For gcc, I can use `printf.h` as shown [here](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_203.html).

How can I do this for Windows (Visual Studio)?

Comment: As far as I know, only glibc provides a feature like this and there isn't an equivalent within Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "bad idea" (tm) - it is much, much easier. more sensible, more portable  and more maintainable to write an ordinary function to do the conversion. For example (assuming widget has an id and a name):

```
void PrintWidget( Widget * w ) {
    printf( "widget id %d name %s " , w->id, w->name );
}
```

Comment: I know it is typically a bad idea.  We currently use the more sensible, portable, maintainable method, but it costs us performance-wise.  Copying a pointer to a widget is cheaper than copying a string representation of a widget.  (The main thread copies data to a print buffer, which is consumed by a separate logging thread that writes to disk).  Our measurements indicate we can save an average of about 1 microsecond per call, which would be huge.

Comment: @David printf() itself is typically quite inefficient (because it has to parse the format string on each call) - you are probably better off writing directly to the stream via function which writes directly to the output stream (not to a buffer). And if the Windows compiler you are using doesn't have this feature (which vc++ doesn't) I can't see how you have benchmarked it.

Comment: Our application is massively multi-threaded so we require writes to a shared buffer.  Regarding windows:  we don't run our production code in it, but some developers like to develop on it so we try to maintain compatibility.  Our benchmarking was done in Linux.

Comment: @David Well, make them use the Windows MinGW port of GCC (get it at http://tdragon.net/recentgcc), which I guess will support the user-defined formats. But seriously, I think you are barking up the wrong tree here - printf does not have any magic performance-enhancing capabilities you can't write yourself.

Comment: Also, regarding the performance of printf(), the parsing of the format string is performed in a separate low-priority thread, which we don't care to optimize.  It's the passing of the data from the main thread to that low-priority thread that we wish to optimize.

Comment: @David And how will writing user-defined conversions do that? You can't get much more efficient than passing a pointer, and that will take WAAAY less than 1ms - I honestly think you have identified the wrong performance bottleneck here. And how have you allocated printf's parsing to another thread? And why would making that thread low-priority help matters?

Comment: Right now, we have a printf-style statement that looks like my_printf("%d %d %d %d ...", widget->a, widget->b, widget->c, ...).  All arguments to this function are copied to a shared buffer, which are processed by the consumer thread, which then does an actual printf().  That copying takes 1us (not 1ms).  If I instead did my_printf("%T", widget), then there is much less data to copy to the shared buffer, as you note, which should cut that 1us into something more like 0.1us.

Comment: @David If the call to my_printf really takes a string literal as the first parameter I can't see why writing your own function (which then calls printf with that literal) wouldn't be the way to go. Perhaps you could could edit your question to include some of your real code. And (speaking as someone who has written lots of MT and MP code) I've never found it necessary to write special logging functions anyway - have you tried just using raw printf calls?

Comment: For the first parameter, only the address is passed (later strings passed as %s arguments are strcpy'ed).  As you can see, the context out of which I asked the original question is a bit convoluted; I didn't think it was appropriate given the simplicity of the question.  Raw printf's would certainly not work - we' need to mutex guard them, and then threads would be waiting on each other for OS write calls!

Comment: The decision we've made is to use #ifdef LINUX #else #endif macro guards around the most critical prints.  unquiet mind, if you'd like to continue the conversation offline, please let me know and I'd be happy to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than letting `printf` do the conversions, provide your object with a function that converts to a string and let `printf` output the string as normal.